# Something like atexit() in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, module, atexit

I'm looking for a way to run a function in order to clean up/release resources when a PowerShell script exits, like Unix's atexit(). Preferably, this would work something like:

```
# A module

function OnExit() {
  # Release some resources, stop some background stuff...
}

Register-ExitFunction OnExit

Invoke-SomeStuffThatThrows
# Or
exit
# Or
# Return to importing script at EOF, then that script exits or dies
```

And then no matter what kind of exit happens, `OnExit` would get invoked. A try/finally doesn't really work, because it doesn't work inside a module where the script doesn't exit at EOF.

Obviously it doesn't have to be a single cmdlet, and I'm okay with reasonably hacky solutions. I'd rather something that works in all hosts (ISE, powershell.exe, etc.), but if that's not possible it's fine.

Comment: *And then no matter what happens* Even in case of power failure?

Comment: Obviously not. Edited. :)

Comment: Guess I should have found that in my Googling... Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @AlexanderMartin Don't feel bad. Event handling is a hard problem.  I'd just like to note that the action is a scriptblock.  Definitely check out the help topic for the cmdlet.  You can pass a function if you'd like (`${Function:func-name}`)